# Using Rails 5, how do I DRY'ly define instance variables in multiple controllers/actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, separation-of-concerns

I need to define the same instance variables:

```
@note = Note.new
@notes = current_user.notes.all
```

In multiple controllers:

```
UsersController#home
NotesController#create
NotesController#update
```

Where would be an appropriate place to house a class/function that

```
def createNoteInstancesVars
  @note = Note.new
  @notes = current_user.notes.all
end
```

?

Is this the intended use of a controller concern or is there a different/better way I am not thinking of? If I do put it in a concern, doesn't that mean these queries are getting run for every single controller#action? I would like to avoid that.

Comment: This DRYness will have a cost: now it's not immediately obvious what instance variables will be available for views in these actions. And, depending on how you choose to implement this, it might not be obvious that some variables are set elsewhere at all. Do you think you can pay the price?

Comment: btw, your new note can be initialized from `@notes.new` (because `@notes` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object). It this will automatically set the `user_id` to the `current_user`'s id for you.

Comment: @MrYoshiji: good advice __if__ they need that.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the method in your `ApplicationController`.

Then add in `NotesController`:

```
before_action :create_note_instances_vars, only: [:create, :update]
```

Same logic in `UsersController`

Answer (score 0):

I think concern is not good idea for just initialise instance variable.

You can write this def in `ApplicationController` and call via callbacks when you need it in any controller.